# Authorization header in Ruby on Rails accessed with key HTTP_AUTHORIZATION instead of Authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http

I'm hoping someone can clear something up for me. I'm using Rails 2.3.5, and I can access request headers in a controller action like this:

```
def index
  if request.headers['...'] == '...'
    ...
  end
end
```

Or something similar. request.headers is an instance of [ActionController::Http::Headers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Http/Headers.html) which appears to be a Hash. I would expect, therefore, that headers are keyed on the name I send. If I send a request however, with an [Authorization](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.8) header, like so:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: OAuth realm="MyRealm",...' http://app/path
```

The following code in the action returns false:

```
if request.headers.include?('Authorization') ...
```

Whereas the following echos out the value I send in the header:

```
render :text => request.headers['Authorization']
```

The following check returns true, interestingly enough:

```
if request.headers.include?('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION') ...
```

And similarly, the following echoes out the value I send in the header:

```
render :text => request.headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
```

Seems like there is some magic happening that I'm unaware of. I'm completely confused as to why checking for the key 'Authorization' fails, but rendering the value of request.headers['Authorization'] succeeds. I'm also confused as to where 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' is coming from as that is *not* the name of the header I'm sending with the request. Anyone know what's going on exactly?

Comment: I spent an hour before figuring out this. I think it's quite confusing: at least they should better document this behavior.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are correct - the `headers` method of `ActionController::Request` returns an instance of `ActionController::Http::Headers`, which is inherits from Hash. If we crack open the source, we see this:

```
class Headers < ::Hash
  extend ActiveSupport::Memoizable

  def initialize(*args)
     if args.size == 1 && args[0].is_a?(Hash)
       super()
       update(args[0])
     else
       super
     end
   end

  def [](header_name)
    if include?(header_name)
      super
    else
      super(env_name(header_name))
    end
  end

  private
    # Converts a HTTP header name to an environment variable name.
    def env_name(header_name)
      "HTTP_#{header_name.upcase.gsub(/-/, '_')}"
    end
    memoize :env_name
end
```

So when accessing the Hash via `[]`, there's a second check to see if value from `env_name` (which just upcases the key and prepends `HTTP_`) exists.

This is why you can't get a true value from `request.headers.include?('Authorization')` -- `include?` is not overridden in the subclass to check for both the normal and upcased version of the header. I imagine you could follow suit and implement it yourself like this:

```
module ActionController
  module Http
    class Headers < ::Hash
      def include?(header_name)
        self[header_name].present?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Throw that into `lib/extensions/action_controller.rb` or something, require it in `environment.rb` if necessary, and you should be good to go. I'd recommend just modifying your controller code to use `[]` and `present?` to do the check, though :)

The *reason* that the headers are upcased and prefixed with `HTTP_`, I believe, stems from Rack, Rails' HTTP middleware. It probably does this to remain impartial about case, additionally prepending `HTTP_` to avoid conflicts with other non-header environment stuff that comes in.

So, yes, a bit magical, but not too hard to understand after glancing at the source, which I'd always recommend :) Rails has some very nice source that I've learned a lot from over the years.

Comment: Thanks Brent! I'll avoid duck punching and just use present? like you suggest. Still curious about the reason, but you've given me a good place to start looking.

Comment: Thank you so much Brent! It's so tricky and weird that Rails automatically capitalize and appends headers with 'HTTP_' :(

Answer (score 9):

According to [The Common Gateway Interface RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.18):

> Meta-variables with names beginning with `"HTTP_"` contain values
> read    from the client request header fields, if the protocol used is
> HTTP.    The HTTP header field name is converted to upper case, has
> all    occurrences of `"-"` replaced with `"_"` and has `"HTTP_"` prepended
> to    give the meta-variable name.