# Accessing custom header variables in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-4

After reading the following question ([Authorization header in Ruby on Rails accessed with key HTTP_AUTHORIZATION instead of Authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311883/authorization-header-in-ruby-on-rails-accessed-with-key-http-authorization-inste)) I have a similar problem as the OP, but the proposed answer does not seem to solve mine.

I define a custom header as such in a call to my locally hosted server (through Postman):

@Igor: I actually use Postman, so I just added the curl code to demonstrate what I did. I guess it would be better to include a screenshot:

[image]

And this is the code in my controller which tries to read said header:

```
def authenticate_through_header
  custom_header_value = request.headers['custom_header']
end
```

However, this return `nil`. On the other hand, `request.headers['HTTP_CUSTOM_HEADER']` returns the value. According to the question I linked to initially, I should be able to get the value through passing the name within the brackets [ ] - is this something which has been changed in newer Rails versions?

Cheers :-)

*Update*: It also works to access the variable in the following way: `request.headers['custom-header']`. So apparently it works to replace the underscore with a hyphen, which seems weird.

Comment: Do the same way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356705/how-to-send-a-header-using-a-http-request-through-a-curl-call
e.g. curl -H

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, it has changed in `Rails 4`. [Take a look at the Http::Headers code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/headers.rb).

Now custom variables are always prepended with `HTTP_` and <del>`_` in your variables are replaced with `-`</del>, except for [CGI variables](http://www.cgi101.com/book/ch3/text.html).

HTH

EDIT: Just checked again, `-` in variables are getting replaced with `_` and being prepended with `HTTP_`. In above link, check `line number 91-94`:

```
key = key.upcase.tr('-', '_')
```

Comment: It's so weird :( Is there any reason why Rails has to do this?

Comment: ahh.. wasted half hour and then found this. thanks !

Comment: Does anybody know why rails is doing this starting in v4? It seems to me based on a quick search that "X-My-Header" is the commonly accepted header convention. Why break it?

Comment: Also be aware that nginx, by default, blockers headers with underscores in them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right, but I thought I'd add a note for people struggling with this.

If you `binding.pry` into your Rails controller, you can use

```
request.headers.to_h
```

This will get you a complete list of all of the headers. This makes it easier to track down that, for example, your header `authentication_token` has been translated into `HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN`.