# Custom headers in request not showing in Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working with a Rails 4 API backend and a mobile app in both Android in iOS. Using **Nginx** and Unicorn.

To obtain certain data, the cliens must send me (among other things) a user id in the request's headers. We're using a custom header, for example `WWW_CUSTOM_NAME`, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972313/accessing-custom-header-variables-in-ruby-on-rails). I'm aware that in Rails 4, I can capture the value in these custom headers by doing something like

```
request.headers["HTTP_WWW_CUSTOM_NAME"]
```

Indeed, this worked every single time my team and I worked in development. But when we pushed the code to the production server, the approach didn't work.

It's almost like the custom header is gone in production. I tried the same thing without the extra "HTTP_", removing capitals letter, and nothing worked. But in development works okay.

Any idea why this must be?

Comment: Are you using nginx in production?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using nginx, [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers) could be your problem

You have two options

1. Change your custom header to use `X-WWW-CUSTOM-NAME`
2. Turn on `underscores_in_headers`

First option would be better I think

Comment: I am using Nginx, forgot to mention that. Just to clarify, the client should sent something like `X-WWW-CUSTOM-NAME`? If so, should I then pick it up like `HTTP-X-WWW-CUSTOM-NAME`?

Comment: You can access it like `request.headers["X-WWW-CUSTOM-NAME"]`

Comment: Yes, I can. I tried it 5 minutes ago, and it worked. Thank you very much. Accepted answer.