# should a http header of 'X-auth_token: abc123' translate to request.headers["HTTP_X_AUTH_TOKEN"] in Ruby on Rails 4.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So really just asking a YES / NO question here; I have seen this: [Accessing custom header variables in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972313/accessing-custom-header-variables-in-ruby-on-rails) which answers the question below. But is this true? It seems like it shouldn't be. What was the thinking behind this?

---

#### background question

We were testing an auth scheme and when we started dumping raw http headers what I thought should be request.headers["X-auth_token"] was in fact request.headers["HTTP_X_AUTH_TOKEN"].

Is this correct?

ie

```
curl -H 'X-auth_token: abc123' -X POST https://www.domain.com/arc/v1/api/toggle_as_liked/4742/item
```

would have a request.headers["HTTP_X_AUTH_TOKEN"] value but not a request.headers["X-auth_token"] value

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `request.headers["HTTP_X_AUTH_TOKEN"]` is correct. It will read the `X-Auth-Token` header, the `x_auth-token` header, etc.