# Rails, jQuery, Ajax - Unable to send custom headers

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, request

I'm trying to send custom headers to rails api, but I keep getting this stupid options!

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/api/v1/surveys")

I've enabled headers I want to send in APIs `application_controller.rb`, at least I think I did, by having the following code in it:

```ruby
before_filter :allow_cross_domain

private
def allow_cross_domain
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-User-Token, X-User-Email, Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Token'
end
```

And I'm trying to send `X-User-Token` and `X-User-Email` headers.

So on my client side I make the following call:

```js
$.ajax({
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-User-Email': 'my@email.com',
    'X-User-Token': 'fj4402SDgsGDS42'
  },
  url: Host.address + '/api/v1/surveys',
  type: 'GET',
}).done(function(response){});
```

And I've also tried `beforeSend`:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: Host.address + '/api/v1/surveys',
  type: 'GET',
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-User-Email', 'my@email.com');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-User-Token', 'fj4402SDgsGDS42');
  },
}).done(function(response){}
```

It only breaks if I send `X-User-Email` or `X-User-Token`. When I send `Accept` and `Content-type` headers only, it works as it's suppose to.

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing this issue?

EDIT:
I haven't mentioned I'm using Devise for user authentication.
Adding the routes for `survey` (I guess you don't need all of them :)

```ruby
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, skip: [:registration, :sessions]

  namespace :api, as: false do
    namespace :v1, as: false do
      resources :responses, only: [:index, :new, :create]  
      resources :surveys, only: [:index, :create, :show]
    end
  end
end
```

```bash
    surveys GET    /api/v1/surveys(.:format)                api/v1/surveys#index
            POST   /api/v1/surveys(.:format)                api/v1/surveys#create
     survey GET    /api/v1/surveys/:id(.:format)            api/v1/surveys#show
```

Error I get in browser console is:

> OPTIONS http://localhost:3003/api/v1/surveys
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3003/api/v1/surveys. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: Could you paste your routes.rb?

Comment: Just edited the post, and added routes.rb.

Comment: You pasted the result of `rake routes`... could you post the relevant section of your routes.rb file?

Comment: Ups. My bad. Now I pasted the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding `:options` to your routes:

```
namespace :api, as: false do
  namespace :v1, as: false do
    resources :responses, only: [:index, :new, :create] 
    match 'surveys' => "surveys#index", via: [:get, :options] 
    resources :surveys, only: [:index, :create, :show]
  end
end
```

Comment: @antonpot did you try the solution above?

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. The solution works, but it's not idile, and I'm not sure I'll be able to use it. It still doesn't cooperate with my authentincation, because headers are changed to `'HTTP_X_USER_EMAIL'` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311883/authorization-header-in-ruby-on-rails-accessed-with-key-http-authorization-inste). Besides, I still have many calls where I need to add headers, so I'd have to match OPTIONS for each of them.

Comment: Yes you have to match `OPTIONS` for each of them or use [rackcors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) instead. You could also take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/dhoelzgen/cd7126b8652229d32eb4).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't familiar with rack-cors, and it seems I the gem might come in usefull. :)

Comment: @antonpot please upvote or mark the answer as correct if it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your custom headers in your application.rb file.

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => 'YOUR_URL',
    'Access-Control-Request-Method' => %w{GET POST OPTIONS}.join(",")
  }
```

In your app/controllers/api/v1/application_controller.rb file set your headers like so

```
before_filter :allow_cross_domain

def allow_cross_domain
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*' 
    headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'ETag'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*,x-requested-with,Content-Type,If-Modified-Since,If-None-Match'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '86400'
end
```

Finally inside of your app/controllers/api/v1/controller_your_are_accessing_from_browser.rb  call:

```
before_filter :allow_cross_domain
```

Check out [3.8 Configuring Action Dispatch](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html) in the rails guide. Also check the console logs in your browser to see the errors you are getting from the above request.

Comment: I've tryed that just now. I set up default headers in `application.rb` file, and I have added them just as I have them in `#allow_cross_domain`.   
Still no luck.

Comment: @antonpot I have updated my answer above. Also I have added generic headers to the allow_cross_domain method for testing purposes

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I'm not sure what do you want me to do with `before_filter :allow_cross_domain`. Where do you want me to put it? What I have tried is, to config default headers in `application.rb` and modified `application_controller.rb` as you suggested. It saddly still returnes the same error.

Comment: @antonpot I have updated my answer above in which shows you where to add the following to your current code base. If the above does not work we can simply chat via stackoverflow to prevent long comments.

Comment: It hasn't worked with this solution either. I decided to use query params instead.