# Generating Javascript Code with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently developing a web app which can generate JS code that can attached to another page. Just like email subscription form which generated from the form builder below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=BB1K&webforms_id=1523701"></script>
```

Instead of generating subscription form, I want the JS code to render image or text and I want to put the image or text inputted to the file storage such as AWS instead within my app.

I'm running on Rails 4.2.5.

The above JS code is generating a form, the form must be saved somewhere in the file storage (CMIIW). I want to make an app which can generate that kind of JS code.

P.S. I'm new to Rails, anyone can please explain the process or is there any gem that can help achieve this task. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the JS code to render image or text and save to AWS"?

Comment: I updated the question, sorry for my bad english. Please let me know if it is still confusing to you.

Comment: Have you know about "gon" gem . https://github.com/gazay/gon. It might help you. By using this we can show generated js code as like a text view. Do you need such kind on thing ? Am i right

Comment: Ranzit, that won't help

Comment: So am I right to think you want a JS script to help someone create a "form", and have the form saved for later use? Like if the user wants a "red" form, they can put the script & it shows the form on their site?

Comment: Ranzit, thank you very much for commenting but I think that's not what I need.

Comment: Rich, yes, you are right. Here's another simple example, I have image uploader app which user can upload their image. When they hit the upload button, it will generate the JS code just like the above example and when they paste the JS code to their site, the image will show up.

Comment: I think I understand

Comment: Cool! It will be very great if you can help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is a [widget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_widget).

---

## Public

The underpin of this is that you need a public JS file to "pull" data from your app & show the appropriate HTML on someone else's site.

This file will be included on the other person's site; it will populate HTML elements on the site with data from your server (through an [`API`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)). It may use an [`iframe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames), but more often than not will just decorate an HTML element with assets from your own server.

All of the widgets / badges / buttons you can put on your site are just embedded JS from someone else's. These JS files need to work with *public* data from your app (IE you cannot use ANY server-side tech with it)...

```
# public/your_widget.js
// put new element on page
// populate with form data
```

--

**JS**

The *only* way you can make a JS file public is by placing it in your `public` folder, or at least a publicly-accessible part of your app (subdomain).

You **cannot** use the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) for it.

Of course, there are version control mechanisms you can use etc, but the fact is that you need a public "link" other sites can include:

```
<script src="http://api.yoursite.com/public.js"></script>
```

--

**HTML**

In order to populate a widget on your site, you can look at the various JS adaptations which exist. I've not had massive experience of this; [bootstrap's JS implementation](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/) would be a good place to start, and [Google's analytics JS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/?hl=en).

In short, your JS needs to generate HTML & output it on your site.

The standard pattern for this is to include the script on your site, place an HTML "element" (with appropriate `id`) on your page, to which the JS will populate with HTML (pre-cooked with data from your server):

```
// site
<script "http://api.yoursite.com/public.js"></script>
<body>
   <div id="your_widget" data-name="tester" data-attribute="value"></div>
</body>

// JS
```

--

**Data**

To populate the data on your site, you'll need to use an `API` - publicly accessible:

```
#config/routes.rb
scope constraints: { subdomain: "api" } do
   resources :images, module: :api #-> api.url.com/images/x
end
```

This would *have* to be backed up with authentication similar to your app (my API authentication integration is a little hazy):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_secure_token #-> native to Rails 5; gem for Rails 4
end

#app/controllers/api/images_controller.rb
class Api::ImagesController
   before_filter :authenticate

   def show
       user  = User.find_by token: request.headers["Auth_Key"]
       image = user.images.find params[:id]
       render json: image.to_json if image
   end

   private

   def authenticate
      if request.headers.include? "Auth_Key"
         render :unprocessable_entity unless User.exists? token: request.headers["Auth_Key"]
      end
   end
end
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311883/authorization-header-in-ruby-on-rails-accessed-with-key-http-authorization-inste)

The above code is just a general example.

It will allow you to [send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258645/pass-request-headers-in-a-jquery-ajax-get-call)...

```
var image_url = $.ajax({
   url:     "http://api.url.com/images/x",
   headers: "Auth-Key": "x"
});
```

---

## CORS

Finally, the last consideration is [`CORS` - `Cross Origin Resource Sharing`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing):

> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows restricted resources (e.g. fonts **& javascript**) on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the resource originated

In other words, you cannot just let anyone pull your JS files from your server. HTTP won't allow it unless you give them permission with a correct `CORS` policy.

What you need to do is make your `public.js` accessible to anyone, along with your `API`. It might - therefore - be recommended to put both into a subdomain. I can give you more info on this if required.

---

> is there any gem that can help achieve this task

Not that I know of.

This is somewhat advanced functionality. You have to know the underlying authentication pattern for an HTTP web service, and match that with a JS implementation for use on third parties.

In its simplest form, you're making a tiny app ("widget") which pulls API data. You just have to know which parts of your app to allow access to, in order to make the functionality work.

Comment: This is great. I'll give it a try. Thank you very much, Rich!

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate JS file and store in in S3 you should do the following:

1. Create a file in TMP folder
2. Upload it to S3

**Creating a file:**

The best practise is to create a Service, for example:

```
# app/services/js_generator.rb
class JsGenerator
  def initialize(some, params, here)
   @params = params
   # ...
  end

  def generate_code
    js = <<-END.squish
      var yourJavaScriptCode = "here";
      var embededExample = #{params};
      # ... etc
    END
  end

  def generate_and_save(tmp_file_name)
    code = generate_code
    tmp_file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{tmp_file_name}.js"
    File.open(tmp_file, 'w') do |f|
      f.write code
    end
    tmp_file
  end
end
```

**Uploading file to S3:**

You have many options. I suggest using [Fog](http://fog.io/) to upload the file.